# How can i maintain state between recursion calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Here is the question I am trying to solve:
Find the kth smallest integer in a Binary Search Tree:

My Algorithm: I will do an inorder traversal of the BST. Each time I visit a node, I will decrement k by 1 and when k=0, I should be in the kth smallest node.

Here is my implementation:

```
void FindKthSmallest(struct TreeNode* root, int k)
{
  if (root == NULL) return;
  if (k== 0) return;
  FindKthSmallest (root->left, k);
  k--;
  if (k == 0)
  {
    cout << root->data;
    return;
  }
  FindKthSmallest (root->right, k);
}
```

However with the above implementation, I see that the state of k can't be maintained between the recursive calls.

I think the state of k need to be maintained in 2 scenarios: recursive call returns between child and parent and recursive calls between parent to child - This is where I am struggling. Is there a way to maintain the state in such a scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your implementation, you are using the variable `k` to pass two different piece of information:

1. The remaining number of nodes before the target node is found.
2. If the target node has already been found.

What's missing is really just 2. You can achieve this by :

i) Passing `k` as reference instead of value.

ii) Assign meaning of 2.) above by value `0` of `k`.

The result will look like:

```
void FindKthSmallest(struct TreeNode* root, int& k)
{
  if (root == NULL) return;
  if (k == 0) return; // k==0 means target node has been found
  FindKthSmallest (root->left, k);

  if (k > 0) // k==0 means target node has been found
  {
    k--;
    if (k == 0) { // target node is current node
      cout << root->data;
      return;
    } else {
      FindKthSmallest (root->right, k);
    }
  }
}
```

Also please note that the above implementation is `O(k)`. With a BST you can actually achieve better performance for looking up `k-th` smallest integer.

Comment: Why is FindKthSmallest (root->left, k) outside the if(k>0) condition ?
Shouldn't it be inside the 'if' condition, to further avoid unnecessary recursive calls ?

Comment: The line "if (k == 0) return;" above FindKthSmallest (root->left, k) already ensured k>0 when it's being called. The "if (k > 0)..." after FindKthSmallest (root->left, k) is still necessary because k may have been changed inside calling of FindKthSmallest (root->left, k).

Comment: would having FindKthSmallest (root->left, k) inside the if(k>0) condition, cause an error ?

Comment: It would. Because FindKthSmallest (root->left, k) can actually change the value of k. If you really want to put FindKthSmallest (root->left, k) into the if(k>0) {} condition, you will have to add another if(k>0) {} right after calling it.

Comment: I have another question:
Following is the code for finding the number of nodes in a binary tree:
    int Size (struct TreeNode* root)
    { if (root == NULL) return 0;
      int l = Size (root->left);
      int r = Size (root->right);
      return (l+r+1);
    }
So in the above problem, to count the number of nodes, I would still need to keep track of the number of nodes I visit. With each node visit, I increase the count by 1 - but why is it that in the above code I do not pass a variable by reference to keep track of 'count' whereas in "kth smallest" I pass a variable by reference.

Comment: In this case you are passing the pointer, which can be considered another form of reference, as opposite to passing the value.